# How to execute web search by voice in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, voice-recognition

Voice recognition capability is seen on most smart phones. Is it possible using Ubuntu 14.04 to enter search engine queries via voice for sites like Google or Bing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes its possible. For this you have use Google Chrome browser
and keep Google as your default search engine, then you can use voice search.

[image: Google voice search on chrome]

just click on the "mike" icon to start voice search. it will look like this...

[image: google voice search in action]

for the first time it will ask you to give permission just allow it.

Additionally you can select this feature in setting as show in image below:
[image: start voice search by "Ok Google"]